# pass data from controller to view inside another view in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I fetched data from model in controller . i want to display this data in view inside another view. its showing blank page.
here is my code..

controller -

```
public function Listblog()
    {
    $listblog=$this->Login->listblog();
    $listblogwithpage=$this->load->view('list_blog',$listblog);
    $this->load->view('Welcome_message',$listblogwithpage);
    }
```

model -

```
public function listblog()
{
    $query=$this->db->get('new_employee');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: `$this->load->view('Welcome_message',$listblogwithpage);`, the second parameter should be an array. I believe that `$listblogwithpage` is not an array.
I think, `load multiple view` is what you are looking for. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 0):

To assign a view to a variable the 3rd param must be true:

```
$listblogwithpage=$this->load->view('list_blog',$listblog, true);
```

Further the 2nd param must be an array. E.g. `$data['listblog'] = 123;`

```
$var = $this->load->view('somepage', $data, true);
```

This applies to any usage of `view`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from a controller to the first view and then have the second view pass data to the second view, you should do the following, always remembering that CI expects data passed to a view to be in form of an array. Take this and feel free to adapt it to suit your needs

In controller:

```
// populate an array and pass it to the first view
$first_view_data = array(
    'listblog' => $listblog_query_result,
);

$this->load->view('firstview', $first_view_data);
```

In the first view, populate a new array with whatever data you need and call the second view from within the first one, passing the second data array:

```
$second_view_data = array(
  'second_data_var' => $variable,
  'other_data_var'  => $other_var,
);

$this->load->view('second_view', $second_view_data);
```

CI is intelligent enough to let you call a view from within a view and pass data from each to the next in this way. Just remember, it has to be an array.

Using the data:

In the first view you'd call `$listblog`

In the second view, you would access `$second_data_var` and `$other_data_var`

`$listblog` `$second_data_var` and `$other_data_var` each could be single variables, arrays, objects and mostly anything as long as they are passed to the view as elements of an array

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
//Controller

    function Listblog() {
           $data = array();
    $data['listblog']=$this->Login->listblog();
            $this->load->view(''list_blog',$listblog');
        }
```

in view page you have to call that data array $listblog